# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\int^n_0xf(x)dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f(x) \geq 0$ be continuous on the interval $[0, \infty)$, and suppose that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx < \infty$.  Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\int^n_0xf(x)dx = 0$

I want to use some version of dominated convergence theorem somewhere, and I have that the integral is equal to $\displaystyle \int_0^1nyf(ny)dy$ using change of variables.  Some help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: See also: [Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n}\int_0^{n}xf(x)dx=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527976)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put
$$g_n(x) = \frac{x}{n} f(x) \chi_{[0,n]}(x)$$
Then 
$$\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n xf(x) dx = \int_{0}^\infty g_n(x) dx$$
Also, $|g_n(x)| \leq |f(x)| = f(x)$ for all $x$, and $g_n(x) \rightarrow 0$ pointwise.
Therefore the dominated convergence theorem applies, and 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_0^n xf(x) dx &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^\infty g_n(x) dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}g_n(x) dx \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: @user46944 Seriously?

Comment: @Did That's pretty rude.

Comment: If $x > n$ or $x < 0$, then $g_n(x) = 0$. Otherwise, $0 \leq x/n \leq 1$.

Comment: @Bungo Thank you.

Comment: @user46944 This is meant to make you stare at the definition of $g_n$ and wonder whether some **obvious** domination condition does not hold. In other words, to make you think (often an unpopular move, it seems).

Comment: @Did It's rude to make someone feel as though their question is stupid.  You can still accomplish your objective of making people inspect the problem to try and answer their own question without coming off as arrogant.

Comment: @user46944 I wish you would stop insulting me. Sorry but I find myself only mildly concerned by what you feel like putting in my comment. Let me repeat: the answer to your first comment is obvious to anybody aware of the definitions. I find worthy of urging people to *think* (a little bit) before they *type*. Why did you delete said comment?

Comment: @Did I deleted it because your initial "Seriously?" comment made me feel embarrassed.  I shouldn't have deleted it.  And I definitely don't mean to insult you in any way.  I was just taken aback by your first comment.  Sorry for any unintended offense!

Comment: @user46944 Now that we arrived at the conclusion that your second comment is an emotional off topic reaction, you might wish to delete it as well.

Comment: @user46944, as you can see from the votes, some here think your last comments are valuable, so don't feel pressured to delete them :)

Comment: @Did I'm not going to respond to this thread anymore because I think it is off topic from the question.  Again, I'm sorry that you were offended.  I understand your point completely about having people think about their questions before answering it for them.  But I really hope you'll consider approaching this situation differently in the future.  Instead of saying "Seriously?" you should be more gentle with the learner and ask leading questions that can help them arrive at the desired conclusion.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks for your quite constructive contribution to this thread.

Comment: @Did, no problem!

Comment: @user46944 Any suggestion of an alternative, more kosher to you, phrasing in the present case?

Comment: @AntonioVargas It seems you would like user46944 and me to fight endlessly for your pleasure. Sorry to disappoint but this won't happen.

Comment: @Did, glad to hear it :)

Comment: @Did Ok this is my last comment.  Here is what I would have responded to my initial question of "Why is $|g_{n}| \leq f$?"  I would have said, "Consider the characteristic function $\chi_{[0,n]}$ that is in the definition of $g_{n}$, and look at the different cases where $x$ makes that function $0$ or $1$.  Can you see why in each of these cases, the inequality holds?"

Answer (score 1):

Here's another, more elementary, approach that avoids measure theory:

Let $I_k = \int_{k}^{k+1} f(x) \, dx$; note that by the integrability assumption, S:= $\sum_{k\ge 0} I_k < \infty$. We may bound $$0\le \int_{k}^{k+1} x f(x) \, dx < (k+1)  I_k$$ Thus, $$0\le \frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{n} xf(x) \, dx  < \frac{1}{n}\left(I_{0} + 2I_{1} + 3I_{2} + \cdots + n I_{n-1} \right)$$ Now, let $S_k = I_{0} + \cdots + I_{k-1} = \int_{0}^{k} f(x) \, dx$. We may rewrite the upper bound as $$\frac{1}{n} \left( S_n + (S_n - S_1) + (S_n - S_2) + \cdots + (S_n - S_{n-1}) \right)= S_n - \frac{S_1 + \cdots + S_{n-1}}{n}$$ Since $S_n \to S$ and $(S_1 + \cdots + S_{n-1})/n \to S$ as $n\to\infty$, it follows that the upper bound goes to zero as $n\to \infty$. By squeezing, we're done.