# Prove that if $ f \in L^1[0, +\infty]$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n xf(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Prove that if $ f \in L^1[0, +\infty]$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n xf(x)=0.$

I tried to use integration by parts, but it does not help.

Comment: You can see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527976/prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-frac1n-int-0nxfxdx-0?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257193/prove-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac1x-int-0xftdt-a?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n}f(x)1_{[0,n]}(x)$. Then $f_n(x)\to 0$ almost everywhere, and
$$ |f_n(x)|\leq |f(x)|$$
and $f$ is integrable, so it follows from the dominated convergece theorem that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n}xf(x)\;dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)\;dx=0$$

Comment: why $|f_n(x)| \leq |f(x)|$

Comment: If $0\leq x\leq n$ then $\frac{x}{n}\leq 1$, and if $x>n$ then $f_n(x)=0$.